# Responsive design for feature Carousel js

Tags: jquery, html, css

Here is simple slider work:

html:

```
<div class="carousel-container">

      <div id="carousel">
        <div class="carousel-feature left">
          <a href="#">
          <img class="carousel-image" alt="Image Caption" src="images/img1.jpg"></a>

        </div>
        <div class="carousel-feature middle">
          <a href="#"><img class="carousel-image" alt="Image Caption" src="images/img2.jpg"></a>

        </div>
        <div class="carousel-feature right">
          <a href="#"><img class="carousel-image" alt="Image Caption" src="images/img3.jpg"></a>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
```

jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var carousel = $("#carousel").featureCarousel({
      // include options like this:
      // (use quotes only for string values, and no trailing comma after last option)
      // option: value,
      // option: value
        trackerIndividual:false,
        trackerSummation: false,
        autoPlay:0, 
        largeFeatureWidth :   .5,
        largeFeatureHeight:     .5,
        smallFeatureWidth:    .2,
        smallFeatureHeight:     .2,    
        topPadding:           100,    
        sidePadding:          30
    });
});
```

and here is the sample: [**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/n4brbcpg/) (it doesn't work, but in works fine in localhost)

I need to know responsive design, may i know how to change the width of the image dynamically when resize the window.

Thanks,

Comment: You are using a Javascript library I guess, you need to include it in the fiddle for it to work.

Comment: I add already.. but it can't be work in jsfiddle..

Comment: It does not show any external libraries in the fiddle. Also there is an error if you see in the console.

Comment: @AnkurAnand: these are the full source code..

Comment: Ok I get it. You have included the library's code here only. 
I am looking at it.

Comment: I have posted an answer. Look into it.

Comment: anybody can help me? thanks

Answer (score 0):

So one you need to include the library code before you call the library function.

Also the library is uses `jquery live` function, which was deprecated from jQuery 1.7 - http://api.jquery.com/live/.

So either you use another library or I suggest you use jQuery version before 1.7 ( which though I would not recommend ).

Here is an updated fiddle which works and is based on jQuery 1.6.4 - http://jsfiddle.net/drecodeam/n4brbcpg/1/

Comment: when you try to run in localhost.. it will works fine.. and your jsfiddle is not correct functionality.. thanks.

Comment: Is this the way you want it to work - http://jsfiddle.net/drecodeam/n4brbcpg/2/ ?

Comment: sorry.. you know..what is responsive design?.. i need responsive design for feature Carousel slider in  js.. thanks

Comment: See the way the library works, you would have to modify the library to make it responsive as it sets the width and height of the image inline. 
The thing that I have done would not work on resizing the window, but if you load the fiddle in any screen size, it is responsive.

Comment: in your fiddle is not working as responsive.. and i searched a lot.. for responsive carousel js.. but still i didn't get.